# Comparing Loans in Python

Tags: python, rounding

I am doing an assignment for my Python class. I almost figured it out but my output is just a little bit different with the one showed in the original problem. When interest rate is 5.125%, I have a Monthly Payment for 189.29, but the output from the problem is 188.28. The original number without format is 189.286. I guess maybe in the finance system, they just simply cut the decimals instead of using "round". I am not sure if there is any way to do that in Python.  Here is the problem.

Write a program that lets the user enter the loan amount and loan period in number of years and displays the monthly and total payments for each interest rate starting from 5% to 8%, with an increment of 1/8.

Input:

```
Loan Amount: 10000
Number of Years: 5
```

Output:

```
Interest Rate   Monthly Payment Total Payment
5.000%          188.71          11322.74
5.125%          189.29          11357.13
...    
7.875%          202.17          12129.97
8.000%          202.76          12165.84
```

Code:

```
LoanAmount = float(input("Loan Amount:"))
NumOfYears = float(input("Number of Years:"))
AnnualRate = float(5.0)
print("\nInterest Rate\t" + "Monthly Payment\t" + "Total Payment")
while (AnnualRate <= 8.0):
    MonthlyRate = float(AnnualRate/1200)
    MonthlyPayment = float(LoanAmount * MonthlyRate / (1- 1/ pow(1+MonthlyRate, NumOfYears *12)))
    TotalPayment = format(MonthlyPayment * NumOfYears * 12, ".2f")
    print (format(AnnualRate, ".3f"), end = "%\t\t")
    print (format(MonthlyPayment, ".2f"), end = "\t\t")
    print(TotalPayment, end = "\n")
    AnnualRate += 1.0/8
```

Comment: You might want to read about [Banker's Rounding](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/26/bankers-rounding/) which is not the same as always rounding up, always rounding down *or* always truncating.

Comment: Note that choice of rounding depends on accounting rules in your locale, for example quoting Wikipedia" `To the contrary, section 2 of the European Commission report The Introduction of the Euro and the Rounding of Currency Amounts [19] suggests that there had previously been no standard approach to rounding in banking; and it specifies that "half-way" amounts should be rounded up.`

Answer (score 5):

When you work with money use the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html?highlight=decimal#module-decimal) module. This allows many different [rounding modes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html?highlight=decimal#rounding-modes). For example, round down:

```
import decimal

payment = decimal.Decimal('189.286')
with decimal.localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.rounding = decimal.ROUND_DOWN
    print(round(payment, 2))
```

Prints:

```
189.28
```

[Bankers' rounding](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/26/bankers-rounding/) would be:

> ```
> decimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN
> ```
>
> Round to nearest with ties going to nearest even integer.

```
with decimal.localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN
    print(round(payment, 2))
```